# ads not showing on my released app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Ok so I released my first app and it got accepted last night. The problem is there are no ads showing up. When I tested the app the ads worked perfectly showed the test ad and hid it when there was no ad to show. But now it's on the App Store and it doesn't show any ad and I can't see what's wrong in the iad app network cause it's down atm

heres the code:

```
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];   
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Might be iAd is not giving you the fill rate. Just wait for few days so that app is downloaded and there are more requests and then it starts giving you the ads. Also it may be possible that in your region there are no advertisement. If you're new in app development I'll suggest you to use google admob which is very promising in every region of the world.